# How to get the first field of an object? F#

Tags: f#

How to get John1 string value from this object?

```
type Pilot2 = (string * int * string * int)

let p1 = Pilot2("John1", 1901, "Laren_TM1", 1)

let name: string = p1.[1]  <<<<<- this errors
```

Answer (score 0):

This is retarded..but seems to work.

```
type Pilot2 = (string * int * string * int)

let p1 = Pilot2("John1", 1901, "Laren_TM1", 1)

let (_, b: int, _, _) = p1

System.Console.WriteLine(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write this:

```
type Pilot2 = (string * int * string * int)
let p1 = Pilot2("John1", 1901, "Laren_TM1", 1)
p1 |> fun (s, _, _, _) -> s |> System.Console.WriteLine
```

Or define a helper function

```
type Pilot2 = (string * int * string * int)
let p1 = Pilot2("John1", 1901, "Laren_TM1", 1)
let nameOfPilot = fun (s, _, _, _) -> s
System.Console.WriteLine (nameOfPilot p1)
```

Though most would use a record type instead of a tuple here:

```
type Pilot2 = {
  Name : string
  Year : int
  Foo : string
  Bar : int
}
let p1 = {Name = "John1"; Year = 1901; Foo = "Laren_TM1"; Bar = 1}
System.Console.WriteLine p1.Name
```